# .click of class get an input too

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my onclick event of class. All I am trying to do how to get an input too from html element on which the `.slideto` being clicked.

E.g

```
<span class="slideto" input="4"> 
    Click it and on click alert popup the input value
</span>
```

---

```
$(".slideto").click(function(){
    alert(inputval);
});
```

Comment: `input` is not a valid attribute, you can use `data-*` attributes instead, then you can get the value using `data()` method `$(this).data('input')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the handler, `this` refers to the clicked element.  So you just need:

```
alert($(this).attr("input"));
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Pzf4M/)

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do:

```
$(".slideto").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('input'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `data-*` for custom attributes

```
$(".slideto").click(function(){

    alert($(this).data("input"));

});
```

And the HTML:

```
<span class="slideto" data-input="4">
```

Comment: Don't downvote this. `input` is not a valid attribute and therefore this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".slideto").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('input'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

. to select by class and this refers to the current item

```
$(".slideto").click(function(){
var value = $(this).attr('input');
});
```